# How to show $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,\pi/2] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$f(x) = \sin^2 (x)$ , when $x$ is rational, and 
$f(x) = \cos(x)$, when $x$ is irrational.

How can I show that this function is Riemann integrable on $[0,\pi/2]$?

Comment: It seems to me that it is not.

Comment: Yes it is not. I didn't see that the set of discontinuity is a zero set.

Comment: I think you are missing something about discontinuities. Say I start with the zero function. One at a time, I change the value at one point to $1$ instead. At each stage along the way, the set of discontinuities is just the (finite) set of points where $f(x)=1$. But after I have already done this countably many times, the set of discontinuities may include points $x$ where $f(x)$ is still zero, if those points are limit points of the set of points where I made changes. When $f(x)$ is modified on a dense set like $\mathbb{Q}$, the full set of discontinuities contains *every* point.

Comment: Note that this is a "discontinuity of cardinality" phenomenon: the apparent "limit" of the cardinality of the set of discontinuities over the course of this process is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$, but the actual cardinality after the full procedure is that of $\mathbb{R}$. Such things happen a lot, so it pays to get used to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is Riemann Integrable actually. It's obviously bounded, but $f$ is clearly discontinuous at almost every irrational (the exceptions being those for which $\sin^2(x) = \cos(x)$). For given an $x$ that isn't one of those exceptions, take a sequence of rationals $q_n \to x$. Then $f(q_n) \not \to f(x)$. We have $f(q_n) \to \sin^2(x)$ because $g(y) = \sin^2(y)$ is continuous and $q_n \to x$. But for a sequence of irrationals $p_n \to x$ we have $f(p_n) \to \cos(x)$ (by continuity of cosine).

The Lebesgue Criterion for Riemann Integrability says that a function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ iff it's bounded and is continuous almost everywhere (with respect to the Lebesgue measure). Since the irrationals are full measure in $[0,\frac\pi2]$, we are done.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The set of discontinuity is not a "zero set" (does this mean empty set?) -- it is a very large set. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: No no. Zero set means a set of measure zero.

Comment: A request. Can you please rigorously show that f(q_n) converges to Sin^2 x, or that it doesn't converge to Cosx?

Comment: Right, okay. But the set of discontinuities isn't a set of measure zero. It's actually a set of measure $\frac\pi2$. And yes, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Sorry again. I meant the set is not of measure zero.

Comment: Okay! I just wanted to make sure we were on the same page. Glad to help

Comment: But in your solution, how can you say g is continuous. g is defined only on rationals of the interval.

Comment: So consider $g$ to be defined like so on the entire interval. Now you'd agree $g(q_n) \to g(x)$. Now just ignore the irrationals. Remember, when computing limits, we don't care what the function $\textit{actually is }$ at the point (unless we're checking continuity).

Comment: So just restricting the function. Fine. Completely understood.

Answer (score 1):

A function is called Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on its domain. We also have if a function is continuous then it is Riemann integrable. So because $f$ is not continuous, then $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Err, I'm a bit confused by your later remark. Not continuous $\not \Rightarrow$ not Riemann integrable. As you said, all we need is continuity almost everywhere.